# when i use IsGroupingEnabled="False" group not able to display in linglist selector for windows phone 8 application?

Tags: windows-phone-8, longlistselector

```
        <phone:LongListSelector.GroupHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate >
                <Grid>
                <Border Background="Transparent" Padding="5">
                    <Border Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" BorderThickness="2" Width="450" Height="80" Margin="0,0,18,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding cat}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle3Style}" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" FontSize="34" Padding="6" FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiLight}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                </Border>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </phone:LongListSelector.GroupHeaderTemplate>

        <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate >
            <DataTemplate >
                <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,80,0,0" >                        
                    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding name}">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock Foreground="White" FontSize="28" Text="{Binding myname}"></TextBlock>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

                    </ListBox>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>

        </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>

    </phone:LongListSelector>
```

when IsGroupingEnabled="False" in longlistselector it automatically hide the group header now what is the solution?

i was used jump list.

Comment: what is purpose of setting `IsGroupingEnabled="False"` if you still need the group header?

Comment: when i put it "True" is hide itemtemplate & display just only group header.